Projections inside an `ee.Reducer()` in Google Earth Engine (GEE)
I am interested about best practices in terms of projections inside an ee.Reducer() in Google Earth Engine (GEE). There are three options (to my understanding) related to projection that I can specify inside an ee.Reducer(): scale:, crs: and crs transform:. Which ones should I be specifying and why? If I have to specify crs transform:, how should I do that and what do I need to consider? I actually do not understand what crs transform: is doing.
Thanks for your help!
